# Symfony fixed elements on the page

Tags: symfony, twig

I have the following problem, I have a template layout.html.twig which is loaded everywhere, in it I have a menu with categories downloaded from the database, and now my question is how to make a list of categories from the database in each controller from the machine, instead of each time download a category repository and all categories from it. I have been working in Symfony for a long time, but I create the API without views, hence the problem. Generally, I would like that after loading layout.html.twig a list of categories has been downloaded without my intervention, bypassing the loading of this list in every action of the controller.

I have fixed elements on the site, such as: category menu downloaded from the database, on the main page I have popular articles that also have to be on every subpage, and it makes no sense to download everything in every controller every time.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would create a `menuFragment` method in my DefaultController, and use a sub-request to render it.

https://symfony.com/doc/current/templating/embedding_controllers.html

Some people will tell you that sub requests slow down your code, but it is not significant if you don't go overboard with it. 1-3 subrequest won't be a problem at all.

Comment: Hello, to go further than this answer, for menus have you tried KnpMenuBundle : https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html